# Updating one row in JSON stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

I've got a longtext field in my MySQL database that contains JSON strings. I'd like to be able to update only one row in the string rather than have to reinsert the entire thing updated.

How can I do that? I'm using Laravel but could do a raw query if needed.

(This is the first time I'm using JSON, so if I'm not using the right terminolgoy, forgive me.)

Comment: Some example data and the result you want to get, would be really useful. Maybe [`JSON_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace) function can be do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your column needs to be of `json` type. then you can use the `JSON_SET` to set a aprticular json key in your payload.

example :

`update table SET`json_column`= JSON_SET(`json_column`, '$.\"$key\"' , 'foo') where id = 1;`